# Using CernVM-FS as a caching filesystem for media

Tags: linux, file-management

I've a music collection that far exceeds what I actually listen to.  How can I have the whole collection available "naturally" when I'm at home and/or online, but only see the recently played stuff otherwise?

CernVM-FS ([docs](http://cernvm.cern.ch/portal/sites/cernvm.cern.ch/files/cvmfstech-2.1-4.pdf),[github](https://github.com/cvmfs/cvmfs)) provides a read-only FUSE filesystem to an remote directory tree accessible via HTTP requests.  It caches files locally and continues to operate if offline provided that only cached files are accessed.

It sounds better suited than [HttpFS](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/) wrapped over a caching web proxy, not sure if any caching proxies do range requests.  ([related](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18632/low-latency-caching-http-proxy-with-user-viewable-cache-directory))

In principle, CernVM-FS should work but caching the whole directory structure locally sounds obnoxious.  I'd prefer if uncached files simply vanished when offline.

Also, I'd love to be able to write to the directories, so maybe an inotify based system is preferable, but they usually require mirroring the whole directory tree.  Or maybe some specialized client for OpenMediaVault or whatever.